# Bind to the CollectionViewSource of a parent control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, collectionviewsource

I have a composite view that is made up by a parent user control (Counterparties_MainWindow) with to embeded user controls (Counterparties_UserInputs and Counterparties_SystemDetails):

```
<UserControl x:Class="Counterparties_MainWindow">
<av:UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Counterparties_Dictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="counterpartiesDataView" Source="{Binding Path=CounterpartiesData}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</av:UserControl.Resources>

<DockPanel>
   <DockPanel>
       <GUI:Counterparties_UserInputs x:Name="UserInputs"/>
       <GUI:Counterparties_SystemDetails x:Name="SystDetails"/>
   </DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

The "Counterparties_SystemDetails" contains a grid that displays some already defined fields from the CounterpartiesData (a list of objects).
The "Counterparties_UserInputs" displays the list of not yet defined fields from the CounterpartiesData that should be defined by the user.

I used to have the CollectionViewSource in the Counterparties_SystemDetails user control xaml and was binding directly the grid to it, it was working (i.e. displaying me the CounterpartiesData details):

```
<DataGrid Name="CounterpartiesGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource counterpartiesDataView}}"
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCounterparty, Mode=OneWayToSource}"  Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}">
```

However, now that I've moved the CollectionViewSource to the parent window in order to share the same CounterpartiesData object in both sub controls, I can't find any way to bind it back to my grid. Would you please kindly have some tips on how to do so?

Last but not least, I would like to display the current selected counterpaty name in a text box field of the user control Counterparties_UserInputs. Would you know how I could access it easily?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just pass the `counterpartiesDataView` as the `DataContext` to your `UserControl`

```
<DockPanel>
   <DockPanel>
       <GUI:Counterparties_UserInputs x:Name="UserInputs" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource counterpartiesDataView}}" />
```

And set the ItemSource of your UserControl

```
<DataGrid Name="CounterpartiesGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

However idf you `UserControl` is already using its `DataContext` for something else you can use `FindAncestor` to find the Parent and bind to one of its properties.

```
<DataGrid Name="CounterpartiesGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=CounterpartiesData}">
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly fine! However I forgot to ask something that I've added at the end of the question.. I would need to also display the current selected counterparty name in the grid into a textbox that is in the Counterparties_UserInputs this time. I've tried binding it but don't find the correct synthax:  `<TextBox Name="cptyName" Text="{Binding counterpartiesDataView.cptyName}"/>`

Comment: you should be able to bind off the `DataGrid`, something like `Text="{Binding ElementName=dataGridName, Path=SelectedItem.cptyName}"`

Comment: Sorry, didn't explained correctly. The datagrid is in the "Counterparties_SystemDetails", the textbox in the "Counterparties_UserInputs", both pointing to that same `DataContext` now so not sure how to access the datagrid from the other sub `UserControl`. Here is my error log, hope it helps: `BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedCounterparty; DataItem='ListCollectionView'; target element is 'DataGrid' (Name='CounterpartiesGrid'); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object')`

Comment: Ohhhh.. If you have set the `DataContext` of `UserInputs` to `counterpartiesDataView` you can just access anything inside `counterpartiesDataView` directly, `Text="{Binding cptyName}"` (assuming `cptyName` is a property inside `counterpartiesDataView`)

Comment: No problems, always happy to help :)  - Happy coding.